# How to insert data into SQL table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I understand the basics of SQL and databases. However every time I run my script to insert data into a table, I get the following error:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (string.string) violated tips

This is my code:

```
DROP TABLE Bag;

CREATE TABLE Bag
(
    BranchID varchar2(3),
    HouseName varchar2(16),
    StreetName varchar2(16),
    City varchar2(16),
    Postcode varchar2(6),
    TelephoneNo1 number,
    TelephoneNo2 number,

    PRIMARY KEY(BranchID)
);

INSERT INTO Bag 
VALUES (01, 'Hayway', 'Jay Rd', 'Newcastle', 'N9R5DT', 09088, 09077);
```

Comment: There are several issues with the code.  But the first insert on an empty table should not be causing this error.

Comment: For once, you create the column  `BranchID` as a `varchar2(3)`, but you attempt to insert a number into it...

Comment: BranchID must be a number

Comment: It is, but generally you want to use an integer type for integers.

Comment: @Noceo I see what you mean!

Comment: Why leading zeros before numbers ?

Comment: Is there already a BranchID of '01' in the database? Or are you trying to insert something with a BranchID that's already been used?

Comment: @Shawn Good question but the code you see is the only code I'm running in the db.

Comment: And I don't believe your TelephoneNo1 & 2 are going to be entered with your leading 0. They are number datatype. 0123 isn't a number. It will convert to 123 to be a number.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could you mention some of these issues please?

Comment: Can you return current rows from Bag or does it give you an error that the table doesn't exist? And can you insert a BranchID of "a"?    <<<< Sorry. Getting blocked from entering the asterisk. :-S

Comment: Very wild guess: you execute that in SQL*Plus and there is a`/` after the last statement in your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation the correct syntax should be ...

```
INSERT INTO Bag 
   (BranchID, HouseName, StreetName, City, Postcode, TelephoneNo1, TelephoneNo2)
VALUES 
   ('01', 'Hayway', 'Jay Rd', 'Newcastle', 'N9R5DT', 09088, 09077);
```

> Reference:
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm
>   https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php (easier to read)

Comment: (1) The column references are highly desirable but not required.  (2) This would have nothing to do with the `unique` constraint.  So although I understand the answer and upvotes, I have no idea why the OP accepted it.

Comment: My understanding was that the issue was caused by the execution engine not knowing what of the values was mapped to the PK and adding the column names fixes it thus confirming my theory.

Comment: Interesting ... maybe he spec or implementation in oracle is wrong then ... can't say i've ever seen a working example of an insert that doesn't provide the column info in one or another. I'd be curious to see an example of this Gordon?

Comment: Also if it wasn't that then what was the issue?